# ASP.NET MVC 5 Routing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following route mappings:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Post-Details",
            url: "{catSlug}/{postSlug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BlogPost", action = "Details", catSlug = UrlParameter.Optional, postSlug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

I cannot understand why Post-Details is used when I try to load localhost:port/Index.

When I change their places (Post-Details goes after Default) everything works great.

And still my other route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Category",
            url: "{catSlug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", catSlug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

cannot be used anywhere. If I use it after the Default route I always get this error:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

If I try to use it before my Default route I get the same result - on trying to load localhost:port/Index, then Category route is used...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit 1:

I am not sure but I think that maybe Post-Details and Category routes interfere with each other... And when I comment out Category route, the link which should be using this route becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Post-details" route will "match" any URL with zero, one, or two segments, because both parameters are marked optional.  So if you register it first, yes, it will interpret the "index" in "localhost/index" as a catSlug.

MVC routing works like this:  For any incoming URL, MVC checks the routes starting at the top until it finds one that "matches".  (At this point it doesn't know/care what controllers or actions actually exist - it's purely comparing the URL to the "url" property of your route.  When the first matching route is found, all subsequent routes are ignored.

So the basic problem you're encountering is that from the routing logic's point of view, "localhost/controller/action" is no different from "localhost/myCategory/myPost" -- they are both just URLs with two segments, so they'll match the same routes (unless you've got literals in your route, see below:)

If you really really don't want to have urls like "locatlhost/cat/mycategory/mypost", you have a couple options.  You can hard-code routes for each of your controllers, like this

```
url:"home/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home"}
```

But that's a bit messy.  You could put a prefix onto all your URL's that aren't a category or category/post url, like this:

```
url:"restofsite/{controller}/{action}",
```

Side note, may or may not help: You might want to look at attribute routing:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer Edward. I though this might be the reason, but I was note completely sure. I was avoiding the prefix you are suggesting, but well in the end mybe I will consider to use one. And one last question: do using attribute routing is better than defining the routes in route file?